# Rails 4 - Layouts only showing half the time with javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I made a little script in javascript to display a different image based on the day, it works fine but half the time when I load the page only the image will be displayed and not the rest of the app(no menus) and the other half everything is working perfectly.

I put the JS code in the index.html.erb file since it's really small, should I put it somewhere else or the problem is elsewhere?

EDIT :

I ended up writing it in coffeescript in the .js.coffee file with an "@" in front of the name of the function and tell call it in the view and I still got the same problem.

View file (app/view/module/index.html.erb)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   @myfunction();
</script>
```

function : in app/assets/javascripts/module.js.coffee

```
@day = ->
 today = new Date
 number = today.getDay() + 1
 document.write '<img src="url' + number +'.jpg">'
 return
```

Comment: If you want debugging help you need to at least include enough code so that we can reproduce the issue. Have you also done any actual debugging yourself like checking the console?

Comment: I added the code in the question and tried to change how I called the function but with no luck. I checked the console and it displays no error, it just simply stop loading the other modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.write` will erase everything in the html before writing to it, that's why you only see the image.
You should do something like this instead:

```
placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder")
placeholder.innerHTML = '<img src="url' + number +'.jpg">'
```

where `placeholder` is an existing element in the html with id of "placeholder"

Answer (score 0):

You can't use coffescript in a script tag* - sprockets will not convert the coffee script to javascript which the browser can actually run.

If you had checked the [browser console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) you would have seen that @ causes a syntax error in javascript.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

When javascript hits a syntax error it will stop executing the script.

Comment: * it may be possible - but you would need to use a transpiler which converts coffeescript to JS in the browser and use something like `type="text/coffeescript"`. Its would suck from a performance standpoint and is not commonly done.

Comment: I see no error with the console, maybe I'm using it wrong. But why would it only work half the time then? It seems that sometimes it stops loading the page right after doing the coffeescript and sometimes it loads everything perfectly. Is there a way to make it load the script last and not first?

Comment: The answer to that is a bit complicated - you have to understand that when you place a script tag in the html body  it may or may not be executed before a script which is loaded from an external file. This can cause so called "flapping" tests where things sometimes work.